# Did the Doctor rescue the Time Lords in the end?

Tags: doctor-who

Just watched Time of the Doctor. The Time Lords gifted the Doctor with a new Regeneration Cycle. (Somehow) 
Without spoilers, did the Doctor rescue Gallifrey and the Time Lords in the end?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that you can easily look this up elsewhere, it seems you want a single yes/no answer with no details, which makes this a poor question.

Comment: Why don't you watch some more Doctor Who and see if it will be answered later on?

Comment: "in the end" - Doctor Who hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in the episode ["The Day of the Doctor"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor).

And it's mentioned where Gallifrey actually is in Doctor Who season 8.

Also Peter Capaldi tries to find it in "Heaven Sent."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should quote the relevant portion of the page you link to in case it gets changed, moved or deleted.  Please read [answer].